# Which order of sort and unique is faster?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, unique

For example in Julia

```
julia> sort(unique([1,2,3,2,1]))
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> unique(sort([1,2,3,2,1]))
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```

Which order is faster? And why?

Comment: "sort" and "unique" describe problems, not algorithms. If a language has these functions then they may be implemented in various ways, and which order is faster will depend on the implementation.

Comment: Have you considered benchmarking this yourself on data that is reasonably similar to the data you care about the speed of this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, Julia uses [QuickSort](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/sort/#Base.Sort.QuickSort) as default for the numeric input. This is a `n log n` operation.

Unique takes complextity of O(n) both time and space.

Now, consider a small input of 10000 numbers.

**Case 1:**
Let say only 1000 of these are unique.

Suppose you run `sort(unique(arr))` then you would basically be sorting only 1000 numbers compared to `unique(sort(arr))` where you would sort 10000 numbers.

**Case 2:**
Let say all 10000 of these are unique.
Now, here there is no significant change in the performance between the two as the sort function takes all the 10000 values either way.

So, it totally depends on input. But it makes sense to use `sort(unique(arr))`.